# Access to Map values in Safari 7.1+

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6

Safari has support for ES6 Maps and Sets in version 7.1 and higher ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility)).
I'm using a Map in my application and at some point want access to the values. Calling the `values()` function on the map seems like the way to go and returns an Iterator. By calling `next()` on the returned Iterator, one should be able to iterate over the values. This works fine in Chrome, but Safari does something strange. It returns a `Map Iterator` when calling `values()`, but the returned iterator has no `next()` function.

```
m = new Map();
m.set(1, "test");
m.set("2", false);
it = m.values(); // returns Map Iterator
it.next(); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is the Safari implementation only partial?
Is there another way to get access to the values? Using the `for..of` construct is not an option because this is new syntax and is not supported in older browsers (for which I use the es6-collections shim).

Comment: If it really is how you describe, then that's a bug.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in Safari (7.1/8): https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/issues/326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed seems to be a bug with Safari 7.1 and 8. I managed to work around this issue by first checking if the next function was available and if not, I used the `for...of` construct. Because this is invalid syntax pre-ES6, I had to wrap it in an `eval` statement:

```
m = new Map();
m.set(1, "test");
m.set("2", false);
it = m.values(); // returns an Iterator
if (typeof it.next === 'function') {
    v = it.next();
    // do something with v here
} else {
    eval("for (v of iterator) /* do something with v here */");
}
```

Comment: *" Because this is invalid syntax pre-ES6, I had to wrap it in an eval statement"* That doesn't seem to make sense. If the engine doesn't understand `for/of`,  using `eval` instead won't make a difference. It seems to me that the linter you may be using doesn't understand ES6, which is a separate problem.

Comment: @FelixKling It does make a difference. The for/of case only gets executed in Safari 7.1/8 which does support it. The other browsers make use of a polyfill that has a working iterator. I can't put the for/of in plain code because other browsers would complain about the invalid syntax and do nothing at all.

Comment: I see. Still. Using `eval` here is not a clean solution. I would probably use a library that polyfills the non-standard behavior. Core-js claims it does, but I haven't tested it in Safari.